# Django crispy-form changes lay on production server

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I cannot seem to understand why crispy-form has changed the layout on my production server vs. the test server. Looking at the html code the only thing I can see is that classes for the form list is changes on the production server.

Production Server HTML

```
<div id="div_id_pants" class="control-group"> <label for="id_pants" class="control-label ">
```

Test Server HTML

```
<div id="div_id_pants" class="form-group"> <label for="id_pants" class="">
```

also noticed that on the test server there is a css file forms.scss.171 that provides the form-group class. Which is not being listed at all on the production site.

Any info on where this might be mismatching would be greatly aprieciated. It doesn't look very good atm :(

** Edit ** I am using Bootstrap4 CDN's for styling

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution to my problem was that I needed to define the template pack in side of my settings file for django.

```
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
```

Once I set the above in my settings everything was working corrrectly.